# Two word document in the same window

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in, ribbon

Do you know please how to handle two word document in the same window and with only one ribbon, as shown below ? (each document can be scrolled and modified independently from the other)

[image]

Comment: Word is not (no longer) designed to work as you propose - pretty much exactly for this reason. I don't know whether the Application-level events will continue to work correctly, with whatever you've done. But in short, you'd need to use event such as Document_Change to trigger Ribbon callbacks to reflect environment of the document you're in. There's an article in the VSTO documentation on working with Custom Taskpanes in multiple documents - this would follow the same principles.

Answer (score 0):

The [Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/application-documents-property-word) property of the `Application` class returns a `Documents` collection that represents all the open documents.

```
Dim docLoop As Document 

For Each docLoop In Documents 
  With docLoop 
    .PageSetup.LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5) 
    .PageSetup.RightMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5) 
    .PrintOut 
  End With 
Next docLoop
```

Also you may find the [ActiveDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/application-activedocument-property-word) property of the `Application` class helpful. It returns a `Document` object that represents the active document (the document with the focus). If there are no documents open, an error occurs.

```
If Application.Documents.Count >= 1 Then 
   MsgBox ActiveDocument.Name 
Else 
   MsgBox "No documents are open" 
End If
```